# How to add warn count to warn command with sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

So im trying to make a warn command using sqlite3
everything is fine

it warns them and stores the reason, guild id and user id in the database
but i want to check for how many warns the user got using sqlite3

i tried so many things but nothing worked
any type of help will be appreciated!..

my code :-

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import sqlite3

class warn(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def warn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
        db = sqlite3.connect("warn.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = ("INSERT INTO main (user_id, reason, guild) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
        val = (member.id, reason, ctx.guild.id)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)

        em = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<:zztick:1067013663535411280> | warned **{member.mention}** for the reason: *{reason}*",
            color=0x2F3136
        )
        em.set_footer(text=f"warn no. {DO SOMETHING}")
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
        db.commit()
        db.close()

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(warn(bot))
```

thanks for reading...

Comment: Use a `SELECT` query to get the user's previous warnings, and display whatever you want from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def warn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
        db = sqlite3.connect("warn.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        # Just for checking if user already exists in table
        check_user_sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main WHERE user_id = ? AND guild = ?")
        check_user_val = (member.id, ctx.guild.id)
        cursor.execute(check_user_sql, check_user_val)
        user_exists = cursor.fetchone()[0]

        if user_exists:
            # If user exists in table, it will update their warn count
            update_warn_count_sql = ("UPDATE main SET warn_count = warn_count + 1 WHERE user_id = ? AND guild = ?")
            cursor.execute(update_warn_count_sql, check_user_val)
        else:
            # If user not exists, insert a new row with a warn count of 0
            insert_user_sql = ("INSERT INTO main (user_id, reason, guild, warn_count) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 0)")
            insert_user_val = (member.id, reason, ctx.guild.id)
            cursor.execute(insert_user_sql, insert_user_val)

        # To get current warn count of user
        warn_count_sql = ("SELECT warn_count FROM main WHERE user_id = ? AND guild = ?")
        cursor.execute(warn_count_sql, check_user_val)
        warn_count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this but when i write warn_count[0] it returns object NoneType is not subscriptable but when i type only warn_count it returns None what should i do?